# calling javascript inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .next().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
        $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#prev').attr('disabled', null);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
        .prev().show().addClass('current');
    if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
        $('#prev').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    $('#next').attr('disabled', null);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>javascript problem</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id='div1' class="first current">
  <p>
    here the content of div 1
  </p>
</div>

<div id='div2'>
  <p>
    here the content of div 2
  </p>
</div>
  
  //then another 9 divs
  
<div id='div12' class="last">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit()">
</div>

<div class="buttons">
<button id="prev" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

what i want to do is have the buttons (in the div 'buttons') in every div and not below. because i want them not to show up at the end, and i want to change the value of it on the first page.
but when i do this, they dont work anymore.

the codesnippet does not work
but what it does is, when you click 'next' the next div will be shown.

here is how i want it:

```
<div id='div1' class='first current'>
<p>here the content of div 1</p>
<button id="next">Start</button>
</div>
```

hope its clear

Comment: When you add the buttons to each div, do you use the same Id each time?

Comment: yes, always id='next'

Comment: if you want multiple buttons you should use class instead of id since you should have only one element with same id on a page.

Comment: if i change that to id='next1' ; id='next2' etc. how do i fix $('#next').click(function() {}?

Comment: `$('.next').click(function() {. . . });` with `next` as class, not ID.

Comment: give the same class to the button and keep the special info of them in data- attribute or something else and in the click function use $(this).attr("..") and do whatever you want with this info.Giving same id is impossible.

Comment: You can use `$('[id^="next"]')` https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: thanks guys! great help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` attribute in HTML should always be unique. Instead of using the same `id` on all your next/prev buttons, you should use a `class` instead. You can then bind the click event using the `class` instead and it will apply to all the elements with that `class`.

```
<button class="next">Start</button>

$('.next').click(function() { ... });
```